# Deeplab V3 installation : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deeplab'

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, module, deeplab

after following the instruction at:
https://github.com/mathildor/DeepLab-v3/blob/master/g3doc/installation.md

and:

```
echo %PYTHONPATH%

$PYTHONPATH: 'C:\.....\tensorflow\models\research' : 'C:\.....\tensorflow\models\research\slim' "
```

and also after following this thread:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4364

I'm still getting the same error when trying to run the test file:

```
python deeplab/model_test.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deeplab/model_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    from deeplab import common
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deeplab'
```

I`m stuck on this for a couple of day now, does anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in models/research directory, and that slim and deeplab folders are both inside that directory. Then, run the following code:

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim

You do not need to change anything in the above line. Then, run the train.py again and you should be fine.

Comment: But for the particular error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deeplab' , the correct export is to do " export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/deeplab" from the parent folder (research here) which contains both slim and deeplab folder

Answer (score 0):

on windows is SET PYTHONPATH=%cd%;%cd%\slim